# Chinese texts in HTML all become funny letters such as '&#38024'

Tags: html, utf-8, ascii, decoding

I am a complete idiot in HTML but somehow I need to make some simple edits to a HMTL page. What puzzles me is, when I open up the source code editor, all the Chinese texts on this HTML file have become something like these:

```
&#38889;&#24335;&#21322;&#27704;&#20037;&#22047;&#22047;&#21767
```

I guess this is an encoding/decoding problem but I just don't know what to do in order to see the source code in the original Chinese texts.

Is there any tool, or any online website, where I can paste in the source code of this HTML page, so that all these characters in the source code will be decoded into the original Chinese texts?

Answer (score 1):

You need to add the utf-8 meta tag in your head section in your html page

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
```

Comment: there was a mistake and i deleted it while submiting the answer but here i edited the answer and added it again , thank you for mentioning